# Blocking Past Dates through JavaScript? Safe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

I have a simple reservation form with a **JQ datepicker** and I set the start date on the calendar based on JavaScript `new Date()`.

Now without making things any more complicated and running some kind of Ajax request to grab the correct date from the server because obviously JS will return whatever time is set on the users device.

The app itself will validate the date on submit so the question is:

1. How many users has computers and devices running a wrong date/time?
2. Is it a good practice to disable the past days?
3. Should I rather allow the user to pick a whatever date and validate
   with some kind of JS validation function or on form submit?

Comment: If you're validating the date on the server, don't worry about it. If a user has a crazy clock, it's their problem. They might even want it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How many users has computers and devices running a wrong date/time?

Probably lots.

> Is it a good practice to disable the past days?

There's nothing wrong with that at all

> Should I rather allow the user to pick a whatever date and validate with some kind of JS validation function or on form submit?

This is the major point. You can use all the JS validation you want, but consider it only a courtesy to the user. ***All*** business critical validation should be done on the server - even if you validated the input on the client-side too. This is to ensure that data integrity is upheld even if a malicious user attempts to make requests to your server without using your front end website.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm validating everything on the server side but just wanted to get feedback on disabling the past dates as it is a double sided sword. Either the user will put in a past date and will receive a warning or you will disable it and they may not be able to select it as their device has a wrong date.